# TOIS (CHF), TONAR (JPY), AONIA(AUD) in Quantlib

Tags: python, quantlib, ois, overnight-index

I am looking for the TOIS, TONAR, AONIA in Quantlib for discounting. I only could find the EOINA, FEDFUNDS, SONIA etc.Do I miss something? In case they don't exist how can I use the corresponding rate helpers in quantlib (python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all overnight indexes were given a specific class.

As a workaround, you can create an instance of the `OvernightIndex` class and pass it the relevant parameters (fixing calendar, day counter etc.). E.g., if there wasn't an `EONIA` class already, you could build an instance of it as:

```
index = OvernightIndex("EONIA", 0, EURCurrency(),
                       TARGET(), Actual360(), curve_handle)
```

where the parameters are a name for the index, the number of settlement days, the currency, the fixing calendar, the day counter, and a handle to the curve used to forecast the fixings.

If you find yourself doing this often, and if you can write some C++, you might also consider writing a specific class (like EONIA and the like) and possibly contribute it to QuantLib. You can compare the code above with the contents of `ql/indexes/ibor/eonia.hpp` and `ql/indexes/ibor/eonia.cpp` to see how that can be done.

Comment: thanks a lot. do you have an example for the workaround? I will take then a look whether I can contribute for other ones :).

Comment: I edited the answer and added the example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. That is what I was looking for