# Set-Up OvernightIndex Quantlib

Tags: python, quantlib, ois

somehow I am struggling on my old question concerning set-up an Overnight index in QuantLib (see question: [Old Question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/36826/tois-chf-tonar-jpy-aoniaaud-in-quantlib/36827?noredirect=1#comment52978_36827)). What I don't understand is how can I set-up the `curve_handle`:

```
index = OvernightIndex("EONIA", 0, EURCurrency(),
                       TARGET(), Actual360(), curve_handle)
```

I have a set of data for the Singapore Overnight Index Sonar. I don't know how to set-up now the `curve_handle` in my example below marked as **xxxxx**. I think I can leave it out as shown below. The code looks like the following:

```
import QuantLib as ql

todaysDate = ql.Date(10, ql.December, 2017)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = todaysDate

calendar = ql.Singapore()
dayCounter_Act365 = ql.Actual365()
settlement_days_sonar = 2

SGD_SONAT_OIS = ql.OvernightIndex("SONAR", settlement_days_sonar, ql.SGDCurrency(), calendar, dayCounter_Act365)

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Discounting curve
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

# setup DepositRateHelper for 0-1 days
helpers_disc = [ql.DepositRateHelper(ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(rate/100)),
                                     ql.Period(1,ql.Days), fixingDays,
                                     calendar, ql.ModifiedFollowing, False, ql.Actual365())
            for rate, fixingDays in [(0.081, 0)]]

# Overnight Index Swap rate
# setup OISRateHelper for 1,2,3 weeks and 1 month
helpers_disc += [ql.OISRateHelper(settlement_days_sonar, ql.Period(*tenor),
                                  ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(rate/100)), SGD_SONAT_OIS)
            for rate, tenor in [(0.0713, (1,ql.Weeks)), 
                                (0.0688, (2,ql.Weeks)),
                                (0.0663, (3,ql.Weeks))]]

# OIS quotes up to 30 years
# setup OISRateHelper from 1 months to 30 years
helpers_disc += [ql.OISRateHelper(settlement_days_sonar, ql.Period(*tenor),
                                 ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(rate/100)), SGD_SONAT_OIS)
            for rate, tenor in [(0.0656, (1,ql.Months)), 
                                (0.0613  , (2,ql.Months)),
                                (0.06 , (3,ql.Months)),
                                (0.0563 , (4,ql.Months)),
                                (0.055  , (5,ql.Months)),
                                (0.0538 , (6,ql.Months)),
                                (0.3356 , (9,ql.Years)),
                                (0.3806 , (10,ql.Years)),
                                (0.4938 , (12,ql.Years)),
                                (0.6888 , (15,ql.Years)),
                                (0.965 , (20,ql.Years)),
                                (1.1081 , (25,ql.Years)),
                                (1.1831, (30,ql.Years))]]

sonar_curve = ql.PiecewiseLogCubicDiscount(date, helpers_disc, ql.Actual365())
sonar_curve.enableExtrapolation()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leave it out during the bootstrap of the curve.  In that context, the index is only used to ask for its conventions.

Later, if you want to forecast index fixings, you can initialize a handle with the curve you bootstrapped and pass it to the index.

Comment: thanks a lot. Do you have an example?

Comment: `curve_handle = YieldTermStructureHandle(bootstrapped_curve); index = OvernightIndex(..., curve_handle)`

Comment: Hi Luigi, thanks a lot. Somehow it is still not clear for me. Can you be please more explicit with the example above?

Comment: You're creating a piecewise curve with the helpers, right? That is your `bootstrapped_curve`.  You can put it into a `YieldTermStructureHandle` and call that `curve_handle` (first instruction above).  Once you have that, create a new `OvernightIndex` instance with the same arguments as before, plus `curve_handle` as the last argument (second instruction).  You now have an `OvernightIndex` instance that can forecast fixings using the bootstrapped curve.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It can also show the fixingcalendars etc...

Comment: You already wrote it yourself in your code: `SGD_SONAT_OIS = ql.OvernightIndex("SONAR", settlement_days_sonar, ql.SGDCurrency(), calendar, dayCounter_Act365, curve_handle)`.  The only difference is the added `curve_handle` at the end.